# What is the best place to ask a question regarding capitalism, communism and nature altogether?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am looking for an answer to the following question from a Stack Exchange site:

> Can anyone mention any books which discuss in details as to whether the animal world (and perhaps plant world as well) excluding the human society is capitalistic, socialistic or communist in nature? And how did the system grow there?

For which site of the Stack Exchange Network will this question be a good fit – Philosophy, Politics or another one?

**EDIT:**  Is there any way to edit the question to make it fit for any site ?

Comment: Seems like a decent question. Maybe philosophy? Definitely not politics. You will want to try to narrow your question down more though at the very least, like stick with plants or animals, not both. And maybe even some specific types of plants or animals.

Comment: @Roombatron5000, `EDIT` added.

Answer (score 7):

Sorry, I'm not sure that your question would be suitable for any Stack Exchange site.

Whether animals/plants are capitalistic in nature or not is debatable, which is too open-ended and likely to lead to a long debate and discussion about various other matters. The Stack Exchange network is meant for quick answers to constructive, mostly objective questions, so this question probably runs contrary to the goals of the network.

Also, recommendation questions usually just lead to various lists which get outdated quickly and are hard to maintain (spam, broken links, changing circumstances, etc.) -- for this reason, they are off-topic on most (but not all) SE sites.

See the [help centre's guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to what types of questions are best suited to SE sites.

Comment: My question does not exactly ask for an answer to  the nature of animal world, rather it asks  whether there is any book available that discusses the open-ended topic.

Comment: Asking for external resources is generally off-topic too. The question needs to be something that can be completely answered in the answer section without referring to external sources except as additional reading above and beyond the answer.

Comment: @RobertLongson, `EDIT` added